# Provide a default value on a field also on edit form

Tags: plone, dexterity

So I have a form (just getting the example from [plone.directives.form](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.directives.form#value-adapters)):

```
from plone.directives import form
from zope import schema

class IMySchema(form.Schema):

    title = schema.TextLine(title=u"Title")

@form.default_value(field=IMySchema['title'])
def default_title(data):
    return data.context.suggested_title
```

Which works fine only for add forms.

So the question is: how can I make this same method be also used on an edit form? I do not generate the edit form by myself if that's relevant to the matter.

Edit:
I forgot something that it's quite relevant: the value entered in the field is stored elsewhere, and that already works thanks to an event handler, so that's why I need to be able to provide always a default value (the current value extracted from that place where is stored) and allow the user (a system administrator) to change that value, but mostly to lookup it (i.e. what value has that field).

The use case here is letting system administrator see the email field of members. The email is saved in portal_membership, but we augmented the regular member edit profile to allow only system administrators to see their email and be able to change it.

Comment: How do you want the default value to behave? When someone edits the item and clears the title field, it should use your default instead?

Comment: IF you do not depend on the context of the form for the default value, consider using zope.schema 3.8.0 and the defaultFactory argument for a field.  I am not considering this an answer, because it is the simplest case, not the most likely.  If you can control the class of the object that is the context of the edit form, why not have it emit the default value on get (and save it or None on set)?

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I improved the question a little bit, hope it explains you questions