# Plone Dexterity forms- Is it possible to set the default of a field equal to a value returned from a function in Add form?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a dexterity content type and I have been following along with the schema-driven types tutorial from the Dexterity Manual (http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/schema-driven-types.html#the-schema) and I am trying to change the default value of a field.

The value being returned is based on a portal catalog search.  The field is an int type in which I want it equal to the highest number + 1 of the field in question.  Because this is a field I want to hide, I figured maybe it would be possible to set the default value through returning a value from a function
value into the default parameter of a field.

Here is my Interface:

```
class ISupplier(model.Schema):

    """
    Supplier of an asset or services
    """
    supplier_id = schema.Int(
                  title=_(u"Supplier ID"),
                  description=_(u"ID that links to the database"),
                  required=True,
                  default=newID
        )
    ...
```

Here is my function that I am trying to use to return a value.  It is outside of classes.

```
@grok.provider(IContextSourceBinder)
def newID(context):
    limit = 1
    catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
    result = catalog.searchResults(portal_type='gpcl.supplier.supplier',
                                                sort_on='supplier_id',
                                                sort_order='descending', 
                                                sort_limit=limit

        )[:1]
    return result.supplier_id + 1
```

The reason I thought it'd be possible to do something like this is because in a choice type field I set the source equal to a value returned from a function:

```
form.widget(supplierType=CheckBoxFieldWidget)
supplierType = schema.List(title=u'Types',
                           value_type=schema.Choice(source=supplierTypes),
                           required=True
```

supplierTypes, the function, starts off like this:

```
@grok.provider(IContextSourceBinder)
def supplierTypes(context):
    """
    """
    ...
```

I did try using default_value:

```
@form.default_value(field=ISupplier['supplier_id'])
def supplierIDDefaultValue(data):
    defaultID = newID
    return defaultID
```

This did not work unfortunately.  I believe I actually may be having a misunderstanding altogether.  If I could have any help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For what I know plone.directives.form.default_value is the way to go, I don't know why it's not working for you. But you can also try zope.schema `defaultFactory` (I used it outside dexterity)

Comment: I managed to get default_value working.  I didn't know that data had a context property until I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138524/provide-a-default-value-on-a-field-also-on-edit-form

That really set me back.  I'm glad I'm able to get that id working.