# Possible to pass title-value onto edit-form via URL-parameter?

Tags: plone, url-parameters, dexterity, archetypes

Appending `/createObject?type_name=Document&id=some_id_value` to an folderish object's URL works. However trying the same with other field-names, doesn't: `/createObject?type_name=Document&title=some_title_value`, will not work, neither with the uppercased field-name `Title`, instead of `title`.

Then, I wanted to read the value of the URL with Javascript on the edit-form and insert it into the title-field, but the URL is redirected to `/portal_factory/Document/document.2015-08-25.2537358109/edit`, so the parameter isn't available anymore, then.

So now, I was about to manipulate the browser's history, to be able to read it of `window.referral`, but that's very bad practice.

Is it possible at all, to pass a title to the `createObject`-method or is there any other possible solution known without the need, to have the edit-form be customized, respectively create a dedicated one?

A Dexterity-solution would be welcome, too.

**Update**:

What I would actually like to know, is the last location of which the link ("Add page") was clicked. That gets lost, due to the redirect.

**Relates to**:

[Provide a default value on a field also on edit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138524/provide-a-default-value-on-a-field-also-on-edit-form)

Comment: I had the same need come years ago, for what I remember unluckily `createObject` (and the old `invokeFactory` also) are not passing parameters to the edit form so it's not populated.
Please note: if you find a way to obtain this feature, it can be probably a security risk (CSRF) and it will probably not work on Plone 5 due to https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13679

Comment: Actually I don't want to send a POST-request, just have a dynamic default-val and am (mis-)using an URL-para to transport that value. The form is then sended as usual by the user (or not), that shouldn't be an security-issue, non? My only culprit is, that due to the redirection, the referrer gets lost. Thanks for the important info about inhibiting CSRF.

Comment: @keul: Feel free to post you comment as answer, so I can accept it. "Not possible" is a legit answer :-) BTW: My reqs changed by now, I'm loading the form into the context and can grab the value of the current page, then.

Comment: With archetypes at least, the edit form has a hidden field `last_referer`, but that includes the view.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Oh, indeed. That wouldn't solve the redirection-culprit, though. I wonder what this hidden inputs-purposes are for. Done as a link, they'll be a perfect backwards-button in the UI. Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could customize portal_skins/plone_scripts/createObject/manage_workspace so that it accepted an optional title parameter, though this works only up to Plone 4.x; the script no longer exists in Plone 5.

Comment: Well, that's an idea, if it works, would be the most direct way, therefore better variant. I'll give it try, as soon as I'm on it again and report back, thanks!

Comment: I had a short look, but still the paras won't be passed to the `portal_factory`-method, to which `createObject` is redirected. But anyway, the approach changed now (form is loaded into the context needed). Thanks though for the hint, much appreciated.

Comment: In your custom script you should be able to retrieve the newly created object and rename it afterwards.

Comment: Hm, I don't immediately get how that could be done and have other prios now, but if you'd had an example, it'll be certainly worth an acceptance of your answer. Too bad about P5-compat, though. Is it true, skin-customz won't work at all anymore in P5? If there's a way with Dexterity based contypes, I'll go for it, right away :-)